# Domain Driven Design Advice

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a Domain that contains the following:

- Venue
- Building
- Room

A Venue can have multiple buildings, a building can have multiple rooms.

My first idea was to have Venue as an AggregateRoot and Building and Rooms are Entities.
Building also have an address which is a ValueObject.

Then my second though was that I need to update a Building or a Room without going through the Venue. In that case, isn't it preferable to have Venue, Building & Room made AggreagateRoots ? Or should I keep it like this? And if so, how to I update the Building & Room ?

Comment: If you are just building a database of venues, buildings, and rooms -- don't bother with "Aggregate Roots"; aggregate boundaries come from constraints on how things change, usually as a result of processes.  "Alice just reserved this building, therefore we need to find another room for Bob, who had reserved a room in the building...."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The decision on whether an entity is just an entity under another aggregate or is an aggregate root itself depends on your domain's use cases.

In general, I use the following rules of thumb to determine if an entity should graduate to become an aggregate:

- **Entity has complex business rules and its own lifecycle**

  Entities with complex business logic and a lifecycle of their own are better kept separate to manage complexity.

  Suppose a room in your domain has numerous states, associated rules, and permission structures (a Manager can perform actions on the room, but a front desk associate cannot). In that case, it is better off as an Aggregate.
- **Entity needs to be accessed and manipulated directly**

  When you feel you are loading an aggregate for no reason other than accessing the Entity, they may be better off as independent elements.
- **Entity and its Aggregate need not share a transaction boundary**

  If there are no business rules binding the Entity to the Aggregate, upgrading it to become an aggregate root is easier.

  Conversely, when you have invariants between an aggregate and its entities, and those invariants cannot be eventually consistent, you need to enclose the Entity under the Aggregate and manipulate the Entity only via the Aggregate.
- **At times, Entity can exist by itself without dependencies**

  For example, you want to manage buildings without bothering about the venue because you are sub-leasing a part of the venue.
- **Enclosing the Entity under an aggregate causes performance issues**

  Remember that Aggregates are not lazy-loaded; they are loaded in their entirety to guarantee that invariants remain satisfied. If your buildings have more than 1000 rooms, you use that much more memory every time you load a building aggregate.

As a contra, remember that you can no longer satisfy invariants by spinning out an Entity as an Aggregate (strong constraints). You will have to settle for eventual consistency and manage workflows where you may find issues while making the domain eventually consistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you model your concepts as an aggregate, you cannot refer to a room or a building anymore. These are to be considered internal state of the venue. You should implement a `VenueRepository`, but no `BuildingRepository` nor `RoomRepository` for instance. Modifying a room would have to be considered as a modification of a part of the venue. So you would have to retrieve the venue from the repository, and navigate your way to the room to do your changes, then save the venue's new state. Also, external contexts would have to not reference the rooms or buildings, only the whole venue. This would need some very specific use case to make sense.

The fact your buildings have address is a good hint that it can hardly be a non-root entity inside an aggregate. You can totally imagine having your building stay in place, while destroying your venue to make another one, changing the building's address in the process. Rooms are more tricky. Rooms cannot exist without a building, so there is a strong ties between the two. Overall, whether you should make rooms part of a building-room aggregate or an independent entity depends on what you want to model and which business constraints you want to enforce in your system.

Imagine you have a business rule that states: you need an executive to approve electrical shutdown of a building if it has more that 5 rooms with any piece of equipment worth above 100k€ each. You need to model your building at the room level, but you don't really need to random-access each individually. This is because you are only enforcing rules at the building level. In that situation, you could use an aggregate. If you are building a tool to help people schedule meeting in a room, on the opposite, then you need to make rooms as entities for meetings to reference them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case, the room needs to be referenced from outside the aggregate. For example, a room can be booked, so the booking will reference a room. 
The Building and Venue is just a way to regroup entities.
So, do I need then to also make it an aggregate? It means that every entity (venue, building and room) will each be an aggreate ?

Comment: An aggregate is a grouping of *multiple* objects, with at least one entity being the root (of the) aggregate. The purposes of an aggregate is to hide internal complexity of your model by having a structure of multiple objects behave like a single entity. You don't make entities into aggregates, you make aggregates behave like entities. If not hidden in an aggregate, you can write repositories and reference entities from other contexts

Comment: Ok so what I understand from your answer is that room should therefore also be an aggregateRoot as it should be referenced from outside ?

Comment: Room is an entity. Building is an entity. Venue is an entity. You don't have aggregate, you don't have aggregate root.